# Run exe file in a server to the client using applet

Tags: java, servlets, applet, rmi

I have Java applet running in a client side as a desktop applicationand want to call exes from server and client machine will access server's exes. I don't know what is useful for this RMI or servlet.

I have tried with

```
Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();  
ring cmd[]={"cmd.exe", "/C", "path for some exe"};  
rt.exec(cmd);
```

But this is useful to open exe in same machine.

Any idea?

Comment: The client machine has no access to the server's disk.

Comment: Why? What's the good of starting notepad at the server? Or indeed any application determined by the client? If you're really thinking about another executable, have you considered the major security risks?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a call to the server, execute a requred .exe there and return back the respose. Servlet will suit well for that.

```
public class ExecutorServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
    String cmd[]={"cmd.exe", "/C", "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe"};
    Process process = rt.exec(cmd);        
    IOUtils.copy(process.getInputStream(), resp.getWriter());
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

}